# MS Access Query Stalling

Tags: ms-access

Fairly new to writing queries in access and hoping that I can get some help with the logic to determine why its stalling at 99%.

**Overview:** The query I am running is based on a table (*Test1*) which has two columns, *Accounts & Payments*, and has about 75k+ rows. Account #'s can be repeated more than once (Duplicates), or displayed one-time (Distinct) -- as well as the Payments. [Table example below]

```css
table.redTable {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.redTable td, table.redTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.redTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.redTable th:thead {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  }
table.redTable thead th {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #A4A3A3;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}


table.redTable tfoot {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #A40808;
}
table.redTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 1px;
  box-sizing: 0.1px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #A53426;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(1) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #A53426;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(2) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #A53426;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(3) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #A53426;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(4) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #A53426;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(5) {
  background: #3C983F;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
table.redTable tr:nth-child(6) {
  background: #3C983F;
 }
table.redTable tr:nth-child(7) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 3px solid #A53426;
}
```

```html
<table class="redTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Accounts</th>
<th>Payments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>42229</td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>42229</td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>55908</td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>55908</td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>55908</td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>55908</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>103848</td>
<td>$35.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Query Goal:** The outcome of the query is to display only Duplicate Account Numbers where the Payment value is different. **Ex**. Account 12345 is listed 3 times with Payment value of $20, $10, and $10 the query should list Account 12345 twice with a listed Payment of $20 and $10.

**Issue:** When attempting to run the query it gets to 99% and stalls out/never completes. Below is a copy of logic I wrote -- any assistance/tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  j.Accounts, j.Payments
FROM Test1 AS j
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Accounts, count(*) AS diffPayments FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT  
     Accounts, 
     Payments
  FROM
      Test1
  WHERE
      Accounts in (
                 select Accounts from (
                     select Accounts, count(*) as [Count] from Test1 group by Accounts
                ) x where x.Count > 1
             )
         )   t GROUP BY Accounts
  )  AS z ON j.Accounts = z.Accounts
  WHERE (((z.diffPayments)>1))
   ;
```

Comment: Do not expect the progress bar to be sensible in Access (or, for that matter, in most programs). It's entirely likely that for 75K records this query will finish but take long, and that the progress bar will be full for 90% or more of the run time. That being said, that `IN` can be rewritten to an `EXISTS` with `HAVING` instead of a nested subquery, which might increase speed by a bit, but it should finish.

Comment: @ErikA thanks for the response -- and so very true about progress bars, haha. I guess I was being too optimistic. I thought it might take awhile to run as well, so I let the query run overnight, but it was still not complete 5 hours later. I'll try to rewrite using EXISTS, never used it before. Thanks again

Comment: I know that feeling, have had queries that ran for 3 days, or, after migrating to SQL server, 15 seconds on the same dataset.

Comment: @ErikA -- Yeah, on SQL server the results return within 15 seconds. It seems that using Distinct in Access slows down the query, if I remove the Distinct lines the query runs instantly -- of course the results are not what I need. I wonder if running a query to show just duplicate accounts then creating a new query from that to further filter on Unique Accounts/Payments would work. Haven't had luck getting the EXISTS statement to work yet.

Comment: Please include sample data in question as text table, not image. Backend is SQLServer?

Comment: @June7 Sorry about that, I tried to insert the table example, but wouldn't allow me due to new profile -- more Rep needed. Also, thank you for your responses -- will test out soon as I can.

Comment: Building text table in query should not be limited by Rep. It's just text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Or the code snippet works as well. I could copy/paste the data into Access table.

Comment: @June7, tested each iteration you provided below. Option 1, 3, & 4 all ran the query instantly and produced the correct results. Option 2 stalls, let query run for 20 mins before exiting. I'll start testing on larger data-sets to see if there is any change in performance as well as adding a new column that includes date range data. Thank-you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 WHERE Accounts IN(
    SELECT Accounts FROM (
        SELECT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 GROUP BY Accounts, Payments)
    GROUP BY Accounts
    HAVING Count(*)>1)
GROUP BY Accounts, Payments;
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 WHERE Accounts IN(
    SELECT Accounts FROM (
        SELECT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 GROUP BY Accounts, Payments)
    GROUP BY Accounts
    HAVING Count(*)>1);
```

Or:

```
SELECT Test1.Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Accounts FROM (
        SELECT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 GROUP BY Accounts, Payments)
    GROUP BY Accounts
    HAVING Count(*)>1) AS Q1
ON Test1.Accounts=Q1.Accounts
GROUP BY Test1.Accounts, Payments;
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Test1.Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Accounts FROM (
        SELECT Accounts, Payments FROM Test1 GROUP BY Accounts, Payments)
    GROUP BY Accounts
    HAVING Count(*)>1) AS Q1
ON Test1.Accounts=Q1.Accounts;
```