# Microsoft Access Query exclude results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a bit of help with sql query for MS Access and not sure if it is possible.

We have a database for our clock machine, MySql which I have linked to access in order to pull the clockins from the database and be able to generate a timesheet.

The relevant tables that I am Using Are:

- Table: Checkinout - Fields: ID, Checktime, Checktype (In or Out) and userid
- Table: Userinfo - Fields: userid, name, company_id and badgenumber
- Table: Company - Fields: company_id, company

I have a report form that is used to select the company, reporting period (today, yesterday, custom, etc) and from above selection a timesheet is generated for the specified company which is working nicely.

What I am struggling with is filtering out all clockout (checktype) before a specified time on start time and filtering out all clockins on last day specified. But in between the start and end date checkin and checkouts but me shown as per attached image.
[image: To be Filtered out].

My current query that is not working that i have placed in qrycheckin:

```
SELECT *
FROM checkinLocal AS CHECK1
WHERE (((CHECK1.checktime) Between [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtStartDate] 
      And [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate]) 
      AND ((Exists (
            Select DISTINCT * FROM checkinlocal as CHECK2 
            WHERE CHECK1.id = CHECK2.id 
            AND checktype="0" AND (checktime=[Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate])))=False));
```

I have not begun attempting with filtering on start date, only end date.

Not sure if this is all info required. But any assistance with above request will be much appreciated.

Original Result

| Company Number | name | Date | Time | CheckType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/08/2021 | 5:59 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/08/2021 | 17:56 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/09/2021 | 06:01 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/09/2021 | 18:05 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/10/2021 | 05:59 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/12/2021 | 06:02 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/12/2021 | 17:57 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/13/2021 | 06:05 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/13/2021 | 18:00 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/14/2021 | 05:58 | 0 |

Required Result

| Company Number | name | Date | Time | CheckType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/08/2021 | 17:56 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/09/2021 | 06:01 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/09/2021 | 18:05 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/10/2021 | 05:59 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/12/2021 | 06:02 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/12/2021 | 17:57 | 1 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/13/2021 | 06:05 | 0 |
| 1 | Peter Pan | 04/13/2021 | 18:00 | 1 |

I got the above sql code from sqltest.net after playing around there:
SqlScript:

```
CREATE TABLE sql_server_test_a 
( 
    ID         NVARCHAR(4000), 
    FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(200), 
    LAST_NAME  NVARCHAR(200),
    checktime  DATE,
    checktype  NVARCHAR(4) 
); 

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('1', 'Paris', 'Hilton', '03/01/2021', "1");

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('1', 'Paris', 'Hilton', '03/01/2021', "0"); 

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('2', 'Nicky', 'Hilton', '03/06/2021', "1");

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('3', 'Peter', 'Hilton', '03/08/2021', "0");

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('4', 'Roger', 'Hilton', '03/08/2021', "1");

INSERT INTO sql_server_test_a (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, checktime, checktype) VALUES ('5', 'Holly', 'Hilton', '03/04/2021', "0");
```

and the working sql Query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sql_server_test_a AS Test1
  WHERE checktime Between "03/01/2021" and "03/08/2021"
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sql_server_test_a AS Test2
        WHERE Test1.ID = Test2.ID 
        and (checktype = "0" and checktime = "03/08/2021"));
```

But above code does not work in access after replacing the dates with the forms texts boxes.
Regards

Comment: Should provide sample data and desired result as text tables, not image, or provide SQL to create table and add records. "Not working" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Not filtering out the required data. In the above sql query the check in rows are still shown on the last day of the report.

Comment: Sorry trying to google how to provide text tables. First thought it was text file.

Comment: Review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow. And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092328/ms-access-query-stalling/67097918#67097918 to see how someone used a code snippet to provide data in question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @June7 Thank you for the information bud, much appreciated. I generated a table on sqltest.net and placed sum dummy data there. then Worked on the query which is working there. (that is where I got the query from for access. Only difference is instead of form text boxes, I manually entered the dates. 
```
SELECT * 
  FROM sql_server_test_a AS Test1
  WHERE checktime Between "03/01/2021" and "03/08/2021"
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sql_server_test_a AS Test2
        WHERE Test1.ID = Test2.ID 
        and (checktype = "0" and checktime = "03/08/2021"));
```

Comment: @June7 After a struggle, managed to add the table. Blond day for me.

Comment: Why do tables show two fields for date and time yet the CREATE sql shows only one field? CheckInOut table description also shows only one date/time field. You describe 3 tables yet have code for generating only 1. Really need representative data for only the CheckInOut table. The 'working' query does not use Access SQL syntax for date/time field. This phrase in your narrative does not make sense: "checkin and checkouts but me shown as per attached image". I never use dynamic parameterized query. I prefer VBA to build criteria string and apply to form or report.

Comment: Is this a split db and front and back ends are both Access? CheckType is a text or number or yes/no field? Sample data does not fit with testing parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@June7 thank you for your assistance, with a bit of tinkering of your code that you provided I got it working.

Final working code was:

```
SELECT *
FROM checkinLocal AS A
WHERE [checktime] Between [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtStartDate] 
   And [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate] + 1 AND [ID] NOT IN (
      SELECT ID FROM checkinLocal  as B WHERE A.[ID] = B.[ID] AND (checktype="0" And checktime >= [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate] & ' ' & '17:00:00'));
```

Your assistance was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM CheckInOut
WHERE [checktime] Between [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtStartDate] 
   And [Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate] AND ID NOT IN (
      SELECT ID FROM CheckInOut WHERE checktype="0" And checktime=[Forms]![TimeSheet Report]![txtEndDate]);
```